# How do I capture the rightclick event for a FusionTablesLayer?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Following Google's documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesMouseEvent

There doesn't seem to be any documented way of capturing a rightclick event on a FutionTablesLayer like there is on the Map object.  Has anyone figured out how to capture a rightclick (or contextmenu) event?

Even getting the x/y coordinates in pixels would be helpful since I could use those to find the latlng and query the FusionTable myself somehow... but it looks like the rightclick event on the Map is canceled or prevented from firing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible.

The map would respond to the rightclick when you set the clickable-option of the layer to false, but this wouldn't help you much, because the latLng-property would contain the click-coordinates on the map and not the position of the marker.